# Custom MediaTrasportControls aren't visible

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to impletement custom controls in MediaPlayerElement. I've followed ["Create custom transport controls" Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) and tried making everything step-by-step by myself and even blatantly copied code from example app. But none of that worked.

I see only MediaPlayerElement without any controls. Then I tried to go little. I've created a new project and tried to replicate example app myself. Well, It failed too. I reilize that i have a mistake somewhere, but i cannot see there. Triple-check everything already and even copied default style into my "custom" one. But still, there's no panel.

**Control Class:**

```
namespace Kinopub.UI.Utilities
{
    public sealed class CustomMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Liked;

        public CustomMediaTransportControls()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls);
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            // This is where you would get your custom button and create an event handler for its click method.
            Button likeButton = GetTemplateChild("LikeButton") as Button;
            likeButton.Click += LikeButton_Click;

            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        private void LikeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Raise an event on the custom control when 'like' is clicked
            Liked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Control Resource Dictionary: [(full code)](https://gist.github.com/Tumist76/0d66ae000ff6f2f2652af545cf0bf3ed)**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Kinopub.UI.Utilities">

    <!-- Default style for MediaTransportControls -->
    <Style TargetType="local:CustomMediaTransportControls">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="IsTextScaleFactorEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomMediaTransportControls">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">

                        ...
                            A whole lot of code, copied from generic.xml
                        ...

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MediaPlayer page:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Kinopub.UI.Views.MediaPlayerPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Kinopub.UI.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vms="using:Kinopub.UI.ViewModels"
    xmlns:utils="using:Kinopub.UI.Utilities"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vms:MediaPlayerVM/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <MediaPlayerElement
            x:Name="PlayerElement"
            Source="{Binding VideoMediaSource}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
        >
            <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                <utils:CustomMediaTransportControls>
                </utils:CustomMediaTransportControls>
            </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        </MediaPlayerElement>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking your code, there are two things you need to pay attention to.

1. Add the resource dictionary created under `Kinopub.UI.Utilities` to `App.xaml`, like:

```xml
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Kinopub/UI/Utilities/resource_file_name.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

2. Add an `AppBarButton` named *LikeButton* to your `ControlTemplate` like this:

```xml
<CommandBar x:Name="MediaControlsCommandBar" ...>
    ...
    <AppBarButton x:Name="LikeButton"
                  Icon="Like"
                  Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"
                  MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder="3"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  />
    ...
</CommandBar>
```

Best regards.